# How to remove lines that start with the same letters (sequence) in a txt file?

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

FILE_NAME = "testprecomb.txt"                       
NR_MATCHING_CHARS = 5                        

lines = set()                                 
with open(FILE_NAME, "r") as inF:            
    for line in inF:                         
        line = line.strip()                 
        if line == "": continue              
        beginOfSequence = line[:NR_MATCHING_CHARS]
        if not (beginOfSequence in lines):  
            print(line)                      
            lines.add(beginOfSequence)
```

This is the code I have right now but it is not working. I have a file that has lines of DNA that sometimes start with the same sequence (or pattern of letters). I need to write a code that will find all lines of DNA that start with the same letters (perhaps the same 10 characters) and delete one of the lines.

Example (issue):

```
CCTGGATGGCTTATATAAGAT***GTTAT***

***GTTAT***ATAATATACCACCGGGCTGCTT

***GTTAT***ATAGTTACAGCGGAGTCTTGTGACTGGCTCGAGTCAAAAT
```

What I need as result after one is taken out of file:

```
CCTGGATGGCTTATATAAGAT***GTTAT***

***GTTAT***ATAATATACCACCGGGCTGCTT
(no third line)
```

Comment: It looks like you want `lines.append(line)` instead of `lines.add(beginOfSequence)`

Comment: What the issue? I got output you shown as correct.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./RemoveDuplicate.py", line 14, in <module>
    lines.append(line)
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'
@FilipMłynarski

Comment: change `lines = set()` to `lines = []`. And keep in mind if you'll be storing whole lines instead of beginning of lines in your `lines` list code won't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your set logic is correct. You are just missing the portion that will save the lines you want to write back into the file. I am guessing you tried this with a separate list that you forgot to add here since you are using append somewhere.

```
FILE_NAME = "sample_file.txt"
NR_MATCHING_CHARS = 5

lines = set()
output_lines = [] # keep track of lines you want to keep
with open(FILE_NAME, "r") as inF:
    for line in inF:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == "": continue
        beginOfSequence = line[:NR_MATCHING_CHARS]
        if not (beginOfSequence in lines):
            output_lines.append(line + '\n') # add line to list, newline needed since we will write to file
            lines.add(beginOfSequence)
print output_lines

with open(FILE_NAME, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(output_lines) # write it out to the file
```

Comment: Hi, I first I would like to say thank you so much for your help! If some of my strands are longer than others would there be an easy way for me to tell python to remove the shorter of the matching strands?

Comment: Well it would depend on how many of the shorter ones you want to remove. For example: `A`, `AB`, and `ABC` all share the prefix. Do you only want `A`? You can try storing all the matches into a list value in a dictionary instead. Something like d[beginOfSequence] = [line1, line2, ...]. At the end of your iteration, Just scoop out the top x short ones from each dictionary list.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach has a few problems. First, I would avoid naming file variables `inF` as this can be confused with `inf`. Descriptive names are better: `testFile` for instance. Also testing for empty strings using equality misses a few important edge cases (what if `line` is `None` for instance?); use the `not` keyword instead. As for your actual problem, you're not actually doing anything based on that set membership:

```
FILE_NAME = "testprecomb.txt"                       
NR_MATCHING_CHARS = 5                        

prefixCache = set()
data = []
with open(FILE_NAME, "r") as testFile:            
    for line in testFile:                         
        line = line.strip()                 
        if not line: 
            continue              
        beginOfSequence = line[:NR_MATCHING_CHARS]
        if (beginOfSequence in prefixCache):
            continue
        else:
            print(line)
            data.append(line)
            prefixCache.add(beginOfSequence)
```

Comment: Hi, I first I would like to say thank you so much for your help! If some of my strands are longer than others would there be an easy way for me to tell python to remove the shorter of the matching strands?